# move to delete, not just close, a question

Tags: discussion

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13375/how-to-suggest-young-girls-who-think-of-mathematics-as-an-unnecessary-thing-if-th is beyond off-topic; it's actually offensive.  It's been closed but I move for it to be deleted as well.

**further clarification:** Whatever reasons I may have for finding https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13375/how-to-suggest-young-girls-who-think-of-mathematics-as-an-unnecessary-thing-if-th offensive are irrelevant. This warrants deletion because it may deter, alienate, or insult somebody who merely came to the website to learn about or discuss mathematics.

Comment: please note that since you expressed a position in your question, people may down-vote your question when they just disagree with your position. This is a "feature" of Meta, and it doesn't mean that your question is a bad one. Please don't take those down votes personally. (Am writing this since this seems to be your first post on Meta. Thanks for participating!)

Comment: @Lao Would you also object if the post said additionally "and young boys who aspire to be football players"?

Comment: @Bill Dubuque "Just a football player. Those young boys could do so much more. They are in urgent need of direction. Why should a young boy decide on such a narrow and impoverishing plan for their life" would be more like it. I see where you're going, and no, this is not because it's sexist specifically toward females. It is somewhat strange that the discussants would assume that girls with a specific life path in mind should be treated unilaterally.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Or maybe I don't see where you're going. Are you suggesting that we should try to exclude more types of people? I don't see any reason that either housewives or football players can't enjoy and discuss mathematics.

Comment: @Lao So, then, your objection is to the characterization of some other career (e.g. mathematics) as "so much more" than that of a housewife or football player? I don't see anything in your question that remotely implies that.  But I do see explicit mention of "sexism". Perhaps you should clarify your question.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Having no upside and a significant downside, I propose that the post be deleted to avoid the downside. I don't want to drive anyone away from mathematics.

Comment: @Lao To me, such a deletion is very close to censorship, which I most strongly oppose. If you desire to say something constructrive then why not vote to reopen and then add your own answer. I see nothing wrong with questions on teaching methodology. If such a question happens to be posed so poorly that it invites unintended misinterpretations then it can be simply be edited to avoid such.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque There is no specific teaching methodology for "girls who want to be housewives" any more than there is a teaching methodology for "adults who want to be police". I am also objecting to the top answer's assumptions about, and judgments of, the students in question. I do see your point about censorship.

Comment: I voted to close this meta question as "not constructive". Whatever reasons I may have for this assessment are irrelevant.

Comment: @Lao Perhaps you are reading more into the question than is intended. The way I read the question, the OP is simply giving a prototypical example of a class of students who may think that there is no need for math in their intended career.

Comment: @Lao Where do see "heated" discussion here? The discussion here seems quite polite and rational. Were there heated comments that have since been deleted?

Comment: @Bill Have you read JDH's answer?

Comment: @Lao Yes, I read all the answers there and here. What specifically do you find to be "heated"?

Comment: @Lao The point of my above comments was to attempt to understand you better. But you never answered the question in my second comment above. Thus I'm still somewhat puzzled. Are you objecting to perceived sexism or to perceived career choice prejudices or to something else?

Comment: @Theo I picked up on that. I've also noticed that few agree with me that the thread is or even might be offensive. As to its being hidden: I did meander across the question, so it's not that far buried. It has a medium number of upvotes.

Comment: @Bill Whether intended or not, I think both are apparent, and perhaps more. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13375/how-to-suggest-young-girls-who-think-of-mathematics-as-an-unnecessary-thing-if-th raises many red flags. By the way, stats.SE seems to have a policy of closing threads with offensive language, and don't consider it censorship: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/679/at-what-point-do-closed-questions-disappear-from-general-view/682#682 They even deleted ill-formed questions; there is no "let sleeping dogs lie" or anti-censorship attitude there.

Comment: @Lao I see no relationship whatsoever to the issue discussed in your second link - a question that was deleted as spam (advertising) on stats.SE.

Comment: @Bill Let's hop on the SE chat. I am getting notified by the SE platform that our tete-a-tete is too long for other people to want to see.

Comment: Would the person who systematically voted up almost all of Lao Tzu's comments care to explain? Lao Tzu is apparently at a loss here.

Comment: Lao Tzu: Per @Bill 's request, the chatroom has been removed. Personally I am strongly in favour of the use of the chatroom when the discussion starts taking up lots of space in the comment section. But I respect some people being not comfortable using the chat feature.

Comment: @Willie Thanks. Please keep in mind that main site is very different from a chat site. As such, there are diverse reasons besides "comfort" that one may choose to participate in one and not the other.

Comment: @Willie: On a related note: Do you know whether one can disable the automatic submission of a comment of the form "@user let us move this discussion to chat."? Since I'm not too eager to use the chat feature either, I feel like being made into a liar by the software when it submits a comment by "me" saying such a thing.

Comment: @Theo: either you or Bill should start a discussion here on our Meta about this new feature. (Earlier I sent Bill a link via e-mail to a meta.SO discussion about a feature request to decline the "move to chat" suggestion. Bill: do you mind digging that up and posting it here?) The feature itself has generally pretty good reception over at Meta.SO, so I suggest you start the discussion here first and see what happens.

Comment: @Willie Below are the links you sent by email. My first impression is that this feature needs lots of work before it will be ready for prime time. 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97166/why-isnt-there-a-no-option-for-the-automatically-move-this-to-chat-link

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95937/why-must-we-avoid-discussions-in-comments

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96914/chat-migrated-comments-discussion-between

Comment: @Theo I haven't had a chance to investigate this new feature, but I did notice today that one comment thread I was involved in gave the notification "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" But one can still leave comments at this point. I presume that Lao clicked on the link to move it to chat. That doesn't seem to be very useful unless at least two participants agree to move to chat.

Comment: @Bill: I don't know exactly what is supposed to happen since I don't let my browser redirect to other pages at will. There is the "warning message" you describe and if you choose to ignore it and comment further, the software submits a comment in your name saying: "@user let us move this discussion to chat." and transfers you to a chat room (which I didn't allow). I saw that Lao Tzu left such a comment in the present discussion (now deleted) and I presume you were forced to follow when you came here the next time.

Comment: @Theo Perhaps it behaves differently based on rep, because I ignored those notifications and was able to continue posting comments. It's very poor UI design if it doesn't explain that it will do such a strange thing in some cases if one continues to posts comments.

Comment: @Bill: I know that "I" left such a comment, too, and then the browser steered to chat.SE. I was about to post a request here that the software *should not* submit comments in my name without my consent. I  know two instances: this one and the possible duplicate notification. I don't take issue with the latter since I know exactly what action leads to it and I'll likely post a comment in this sense anyway; however, the former implies a proposal of mine that I don't agree with and makes me a liar if I don't follow to the chat room.

Comment: @Theo I was able to leave comments without the redirect or auto-generated comment, so it may be rep related. I too find such forgeries *very* unnerving.

Comment: @theo incorrect; you must explicitly click the "move discussion to chat" for that to happen. And even if you do, you can delete the comment.

Comment: @Jeff: Okay, that's a relief! Thanks for clearing that up. I must have clicked that link by accident, then.

Comment: @Theo Are you saying that the person who voted up my comments should explain why http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13375/how-to-suggest-young-girls-who-think-of-mathematics-as-an-unnecessary-thing-if-th is offensive? I went into detail in response to @Jonas and @Mariano, and if you're curious for an even longer explanation you can look at the past edits to the OP. It's worth keeping in mind that the post need not offend *you*, but merely should be potentially offensive to someone interested in mathematics.

Comment: @Bill Sorry about the chat troubles. Chat.SE doesn't work with the Midori browser (although Midori passes all of the "tests"), which I use -- but I guess that's moot if you didn't want to join in. The criterion across SE sites for deletion is that a post should be "very low quality" or spam. Although the topic is a spam post, http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/679/at-what-point-do-closed-questions-disappear-from-general-view/682#682 mentions language as a reason for deleting a question. I think math.se/13375 is very low quality.

Comment: @Lao Tzu: Yes, that's precisely what I'm saying. I could not follow you, and I interpreted the votes as indications that somebody could, so I was curious to hear it in other, less and clearer words. I am of course aware that it need not offend *me*.

Comment: @Theo I'll try since the other person hasn't. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13375/how-to-suggest-young-girls-who-think-of-mathematics-as-an-unnecessary-thing-if-th should be considered offensive because (1) the Q assumes housewives-to-be are homogeneous; (2) the top A implies that housewife is a bad career choice, as well as saying "these girls need guidance" based on presumptions about them. Sorry if it's still unclear.

Comment: The question was deleted.   It just took 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

Why I think that the question is very off-topic to the main site, I cannot see how it is offensive: the situation described in its first paragraph does occur in practice.

Comment: Young girls sometimes want to be housewives. But the assumption that those three properties (age, sex, and 1 goal) are enough to describe someone's learning style is presumptuous.

Comment: A simple title edit is all that is necessary here (at least to remove the drive-by perception of harm), and it is done. Editing: be bold.

Comment: @Jeff, neither "housewife" nor "just a housewife" is the issue -- it's the (non-mathematical) presupposition that we can speculate about people based on sparse personal details.

Comment: @Lao: The question clearly asks about *girls who think that math is unnecessary*, and *most of the girls with whom the OP interacted in such and such circumstances*. It is really a far stretch to go from this to saying that the post somehow asserts "those three properties (age, sex, and 1 goal) are enough to describe someone's learning style", or that it even assumes that is the case.

Comment: @Mariano If those three properties are insufficient to answer, then no answer should be given without asking for more detail. If an answer is given, it implies that there is sufficient information in the question. Many answers all over math.SE ask for clarifying information. The answers to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13375/how-to-suggest-young-girls-who-think-of-mathematics-as-an-unnecessary-thing-if-th do not ask for further clarification beyond the fact that these people are young, female, and want to be housewives (or should I say, "merely housewives").

Comment: @mariano regardless, I think this question is a bit of a "broken window" (that is, its presence even in closed form is a negative, and may invite others like it) and I would support its deletion on the whole. http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/1982/03/broken-windows/4465/

Comment: @Lao Tzu: I don't see how answering a question without first asking for further clarification is offensive.  I'm guilty of doing so in this thread, but I'll try to fix this:  Will you please elaborate on what you find offensive?

Comment: I agree with Jeff here. No matter how good the answers (which probably have served their purpose anyway), this question is not appropriate and IMO, ought to be deleted: to avoid having broken windows around. I have cast my vote to delete.

Comment: @Jeff: the question has been around for 6 months... and it has not invited since other questions like it, as far as I know. So if it is a bit of a broken window, it is infinitessimally so.

Comment: @mariano it is currently wasting your time, my time, and the time of others posting here on meta. So its cost is in my opinion rather high already.

Comment: @Jonas The normal assumption on math.SE is that crystal clarity is necessary to properly answer a question. Eg Qiaochu Yuan's top answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17733/non-scientific-questions-solved-by-mathematics asked _exactly what_ the question asker meant. But somehow "Young girl who wants to be a housewife" is enough information to draw conclusions. Not only that, what purpose does a mathematics site have weighing in about what life path people should take ("just a housewife"? You could be so much more, little girl! you could be an astronaut!)

Comment: @Jeff: please leave me the task of evaluating my usage of my time :)

Comment: @Jeff The users of Math.SE should decide these issues, not SE admins who visit the site only rarely.

Comment: @bill where did I say otherwise? We still have network-level policies that will be enforced in some cases (not in this one, but sometimes). I'm fine with my edit to remove the most obvious problem in the title.